# Emulator views only show the values from sw320dp?

Tags: java, android, dimensions, screen-size, android-screen-support

I have 5 dimens folders with smallest width qualifiers.

- sw240dp

  ```
  <dimen name="album_size">200.1dp</dimen>
  ```
- sw320dp

  ```
  <dimen name="album_size">266.7dp</dimen>
  ```
- sw480dp

  ```
  <dimen name="album_size">400dp</dimen>
  ```
- sw600dp (for tablets)

  ```
  <dimen name="album_size">501dp</dimen>
  ```

**What i found in android documentation for screen support**

```
320dp: a typical phone screen (240x320 ldpi, 320x480 mdpi, 480x800 hdpi, etc).
480dp: a large phone screen ~5" (480x800 mdpi).
600dp: a 7” tablet (600x1024 mdpi).
```

All emulators from 3.7 inch till 6.0 only show the value from my dimens.xml file in sw320dp.

**My layout file i want to support on different screen sizes**

```
 <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    android:id="@+id/mSongAlbumCons"
    android:layout_width="@dimen/album_size"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/album_size"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/playerControls"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/mBottomSheet">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/mAlbumArt"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/album_size"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/album_size"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:src="@drawable/image2" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

So yeah my problem is that my width and height for the album art is the same on a 3.7 inch screen as on a 6.0 inch screen.

What is the reason android only shows the value from sw320dp folder?

Thanks,

**EDIT**

For sw600dp it works just fine, only for 3.7 - 6.0 devices it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Please use this gradle. it's supported in all devices

> implementation 'com.intuit.sdp:sdp-android:1.0.6'

How to use:

> android:textSize="@dimen/_16sdp"